# Zero pad function trim extra leading zeros

Tags: algorithm, strings, .net, vb.net

Here is a zero pad function I have:

```
''' <summary>
''' Take a number string and zero pad it to the specified length.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="Number">The string representation of the value that will be zero-padded.</param>
''' <param name="ToLength">The length of the string that will result after the zero-padding.</param>
''' <param name="TrimExtraZeroes">An optional boolean which, when true, indicates that any 
''' extra leading zeroes that make the string longer than the desired length should be removed.</param>
''' <returns>A value which is the same as <paramref name="Number" /> but zero padded to the length specified by <paramref name="ToLength" />.</returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Friend Function ZeroPad(ByVal Number As String, ByVal ToLength As Integer, Optional ByVal TrimExtraZeroes As Boolean = False) As String
    Const ZeroChar = "0"c

    Select Case Number.Length
        Case Is < ToLength
            Return New String(ZeroChar, ToLength - Number.Length) & Number
        Case Is = ToLength
            Return Number
        Case Is > ToLength
            ZeroPad = Number

            If (TrimExtraZeroes) Then
                Do While ZeroPad.StartsWith(ZeroChar) AndAlso ZeroPad.Length > ToLength
                    ZeroPad = ZeroPad.Substring(1)
                Loop
            End If
        Case Else
            'This case can never occur, but it's here to suppress compiler warning.
            Throw New InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Unknown number length: {0}", Number.Length))
    End Select
End Function
```

Now, focusing on just one portion of it -- the part that trims leading zeros:

```
Do While ZeroPad.StartsWith(ZeroChar) AndAlso ZeroPad.Length > ToLength
    ZeroPad = ZeroPad.Substring(1)
Loop
```

is there a more efficient, cleaner, or "slick" way to do this other than looping?

Comment: Why is Number a String? I would recommend you store all numbers as their proper type (int, double) and convert them to string only when displaying them on screen. This would simplify your function a lot.

Comment: @the_lotus -- I wrote this function a long time ago originally to zero-pad client and matter "numbers" in software I write for the law firm where I work.  A client or matter "number" can actually have alphabetical characters, e.g. "045CN".  I agree that it's improperly named, but I use it out of an old code snippet that I've never revisited.  I'll probably change it to "numericalTextValue" or something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Naming**

Based on the naming guidelines parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing.

**Select Case**

If you omitt the `Case Is > ToLength` and the else part aka having only 2 cases you will have

```
Friend Function ZeroPad(ByVal Number As String, ByVal ToLength As Integer, Optional ByVal TrimExtraZeroes As Boolean = False) As String
    Const ZeroChar = "0"c

    Select Case Number.Length
        Case Is < ToLength
            Return New String(ZeroChar, ToLength - Number.Length) & Number
        Case Is = ToLength
            Return Number
     End Select

     If (TrimExtraZeroes) Then
         Do While Number.StartsWith(ZeroChar) AndAlso Number.Length > ToLength
             Number = Number.Substring(1)
         Loop
     End If
    Return Number
End Function
```

Why don't you use the built in [`String.PadLeft()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx) method which would obsolete the `Select Case`. In addition to first stripping any `0` of the left side of `Number` you won't need the loop at all.

This boils down to only this

```
Friend Function ZeroPad(ByVal Number As String, ByVal ToLength As Integer, Optional ByVal TrimExtraZeroes As Boolean = False) As String
    Const ZeroChar = "0"c
    If (TrimExtraZeroes) Then
        Number = Number.TrimStart({ZeroChar})
    End If
    Return Number.PadLeft(ToLength, ZeroChar)
End Function
```

**Update**
Some timetables for calling both methods 1.000.000 times

```
                                    Yours(ms)  Mine(ms)
ZeroPad("0000000001", 2, False)       227       231
ZeroPad("0000000001", 2, True)       1696       297
ZeroPad("01", 2, False)               251       235
ZeroPad("01", 2, True)                248       263  
ZeroPad("01", 12, False)              256       247
ZeroPad("01", 12, True)               257       260
```

Comment: Interesting data, that it's faster to trim all the leading zeros first and build it back up.

Answer (score 4):

So, what does this function do again? Does it leftpad a number with zeros, or does it strip them away? It does *both* and that breaks the single responsibility principle. *Kind of*...

You could rename it `FormatString` and then its name would reflect it's one responsibility. The only problem with that is we already have `String.Format`, but I'll get back to that. First, I want to talk about this.

> ```
> ByVal Number As String
> ```

Number. As. String.

Let that sink in for a second. You're passing a *Number* into your function as a *String*. If that doesn't smell funny, I'm not quite sure what does. In fact, your function doesn't care at all if what it's padding is a number or not.

```
Console.WriteLine(ZeroPad("HelloWorld",20))
' 0000000000HelloWorld
```

I'm not sure if that's expected behavior or not, but I'm not sure it matters. I don't really think you need a special function to accomplish what you're doing. Just take your number and `Format` it. If the data is coming in as a string, then simply cast it to a value first.

```
Dim originalValue As String = "01234"
Dim newValue As Integer

If Int32.TryParse(originalValue, newValue) Then
    Dim finalValue As String 
    finalValue = newValue.ToString("0000000000")

    Console.WriteLine(finalValue)
End If
```

If `TryParse` fails, you could return the original string. If you don't want the original value if it's not a number, you could use [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and catch the appropriate exceptions.

TL;DR
I don't think you need to do this at all. Sorry.

---

It just occured to me that you might not want to repeat this code each time you need to pad to a different length, so you *could* wrap it in a function like this. (Even though I still *hate* passing in a number as a string.)

```
Friend Shared Function ZeroPad(ByVal Number As String, ByVal ToLength As Integer)
    Dim value As Integer

    If Int32.TryParse(Number, value) Then
        Return value.ToString(new String("0", ToLength))
    Else
        Return Number
    End If
End Function
```

[IDEOne here](https://ideone.com/YdTSca)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop and count the characters until `zeropad.charAt(count)` isn't `ZeroChar` or the remaining length is equal to the desired length and then take the `substring(count)` to return

Comment: That would trim all leading `ZeroChar` characters instead of just the number that makes the length equal to `Tolength`.  If that were what I wanted to do, I'd just use `ZeroPad.TrimStart(ZeroChar)`.